# Recursive definition hangs indefintely

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement exercise 5 of [CIS 194 - Homework 6](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/06-laziness.pdf)

This is my implementations;

```
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)

streamRepeat :: a -> Stream a
streamRepeat a = Cons a (streamRepeat a)

streamMap :: (a -> b) -> Stream a -> Stream b
streamMap f (Cons xval xlist) = Cons (f xval) (streamMap f xlist)

interleaveStreams :: Stream a -> Stream a -> Stream a
interleaveStreams (Cons afirst arest) (Cons bfirst brest) = 
    Cons afirst (Cons bfirst (interleaveStreams arest brest))

ruler :: Stream Integer
ruler = interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 0) (streamMap succ ruler)
```

However, when I try to get even the first value from the Stream, it hangs indefinitely. How can I make this recursive definition work lazily?

Comment: What's your definition of `streamRepeat`?

Comment: At first sight it looks like `streamRepeat` might be "blocking", so never yielding a (partial) result. Nevertheless, you should use *irrefutable patterns* here on the second parameter of `interleaveStreams`.

Comment: @chepner Edited the question to include streamRepeat

Comment: Looks like the problem is that `interleaveStreams` pattern matches using a strict pattern on its second argument, thus when you call it in the definition of `ruler`, `streamMap succ ruler` needs to be evaluated which in turns requires `ruler` to be evaluated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`interleaveStreams` is strict in both its arguments, and `streamMap` is strict in it second argument, so evaluating `ruler` even one step requires evaluating `ruler` one step which requires ...

The simplest solution is to make `interleaveStreams` lazy in its second argument, so that you don't need to evaluate `ruler` recursively until you've gotten at least one value from it.

```
interleaveStreams :: Stream a -> Stream a -> Stream a
interleaveStreams (Cons afirst arest) b = 
    let (Cons bfirst brest) = b 
    in Cons afirst (Cons bfirst (interleaveStreams arest brest))
```

Now

```
ruler == interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 0) (streamMap succ ruler)
      == let (Cons bfirst brest) = streamMap succ ruler
         in Cons 0 (Cons bfirst brest)
```

When we try to pattern match on `ruler`, we can get the first 0 without having to evaluate `ruler` further, which means when we *do* try to evaluate `streamMap succ ruler`, *it* can produce a first value (because we know that `ruler` starts with `0`).

A simpler way to do this is to use a lazy pattern:

```
interleaveStreams :: Stream a -> Stream a -> Stream a
interleaveStreams (Cons afirst arest) ~(Cons bfirst brest) = 
    Cons afirst (Cons bfirst (interleaveStreams arest brest))
```

which desugars to the first example.

---

Another solution would be to hardcode the first element of `ruler` and reverse the arguments to `interleaveStreams`, i.e.,

```
ruler = Cons 0 $ interleaveStreams (streamMap succ ruler) (streamRepeat 0)
```

which makes `ruler` work but doesn't fix `interleaveStreams` in general.